# MKMapView crashes on reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am using MKMapView with annotations.

This is my code.

```
-(void) addAnnotationForCountry {
    [self reloadSiteList];
    [_compoundDetail.sidebar setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [_compoundDetail.detailWindow setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    if (_diseaseTable.userInteractionEnabled) {
    [_diseaseTable setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    _sitecount = 0;
    _radius = 0;
    NSMutableArray *site = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    site = [_siteList copy];
    for (Site *s in site) {
        if ([s.country isEqualToString:selectedCountry.country] && _sitecount < 20) {
            MKPointAnnotation *annot = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            annot.title = [s city];
            annot.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(s.lat, s.log);
            [_mapView addAnnotation:annot];
            _sitecount++;
        }
    }
    if (!_sitecount) {
        [self showNoSiteAvailbleView];
        _radius = 500;
    }
    if (_sitecount && _radius < 100) {
        _radius = 100;
    }
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 100;
    span.longitudeDelta = 100;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(selectedCountry.lat, selectedCountry.log);
        [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }
}
```

This is what is being done.

1. User select the country from a list.
2. Read the coordinates of specific country from database.
3. Based on country coordinates selected, fetch records (sites coordinates) from database.
4. Add annotation for each record in Map.
   Note : i have approximately 250 annotations to be displayed on map

This code works and display annotations properly on first load, but when i switch to another SubView and come back to this SubView it crashes with following message.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class '_NSZombie_NSException'
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

When i try changing the value to display only 20 annotations it works and no crash happens.

What could be the issue ? this is bugging me out since  a very long time now.

P.S: I have no idea about Memory management using Instruments. i tried but without any result till now.

Any type of help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKAnnotationView *mapAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    mapAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_icon.png"];
    return mapAnnotationView;
}

-(void)reloadSiteList {
    _siteList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _trialRefList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _trialRefList = [[PipelineDatabase initializeDatabase] getTrialReflistForDisease:_selectedDisease];
    for (NSString *ref in _trialRefList) {
        [_siteList addObjectsFromArray:[[PipelineDatabase initializeDatabase] getSitesByRef:ref]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide code for: `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation` and for `reloadSiteList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. Even though they shouldn't directly produce a zombie, I'll point out to some of them:

1

```
MKAnnotationView *mapAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
```

You'd better to use an reuseIdentifier to avoid redundant MKAnnotationView creation. You should do something like this instead:

```
static NSString *ident = @"siteAnnotation";
MKAnnotationView *mapAnnotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:ident];
if (mapAnnotationView == nil)
     mapAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:ident];
```

2 You only add annotations to map, but it seems to be logical to remove them using `removeAnnotations:` method like:

```
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
```

3

```
NSMutableArray *site = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
site = [_siteList copy];
```

It is a wrong way. You initialize a new object and immediately overwrite it with another. The correct way is to do:

```
NSArray *site = [_siteList copy];
```

But even this is not necessary, as I see your code doesn't use async setting _siteList, so you can just use

```
site = _siteList;
```

or ever use _siteList instead of site.

4 I hope that you're using ARC in other case there are a lot of other memory-related problems

Comment: Yes, i am using ARC since the BaseSDK is 6.0 for the app.i made all the changes suggested by you, i tried Moving MapViewController to parent controller, still Zombie keeps showing up.

Answer (score 1):

You got a zombie, your object is being ref counted to 0 and then you are trying to access it without instantiating it.
Try to put MKMapView object in parent controller's property, so it lifecycle won't be affected by switching with subviews.

Comment: Let me try moving MKMapView to parent controller, thanks for suggestion.